# Socket IO Performance cost comparison between rooms and events

Tags: node.js, socket.io, performance-testing, socket.io-redis

In my application, i'm using redis adapter for socket.io

I have scenario where I have to create chat rooms for a chat between two people dynamically

But I already have rooms for their userid

Now, is there a benefit of performance when I create chat Rooms and publish events to that alone? or when I publish multiple events to userId room ?

Which one is better.?

Is there any performance benchmark tool which can give us the details about the cpu load and network load

Im aware of the http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/ and https://github.com/M6Web/websocket-bench but those doesn't help in the cpu load and memory load

Please guide me on this